# Azure: Get users assigned to enterprise application in Node JS/Power shell script?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

How to get the list of all the users assigned to an Azure enterprise app?

I looked into the Azure documentation, but was unable to get any API to solve this.

Comment: Any more question? Or if it's helpful you can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the user account for an Azure enterprise app through Powershell like this:

```
$app_name = "[app display name]"
$sp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "displayName eq '$app_name'"
$assignments = Get-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $sp.ObjectId -All $true
$assignments  # this will show all the users associated to the principal
```

It will like this:

[image]

Hope this will help you. Any more question please give me the message.