# Azure enterprise application get email of assigned users

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm working on a B2B service that required an Azure AD connection to setup user accounts for all members of the Azure AD domain. I need first name, last name and email for this.

At first I just used the Users.Read.All permission to read all user objects, but some of our clients use AD to store different information aswel.

I'm looking for a solution where I can only access user and groups assigned to the enterprise application by the client.

I've found the servicePrincipal api, but this service doesn't return the user's email.
When calling this api through: [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/{applicationId}/appRoleAssignedTo](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/%7BapplicationId%7D/appRoleAssignedTo)
The response looks something like this:

```
    {
      "id": "41W1zT6z1U-kJxf62svfp1HFE8pMZhxDun-ThPczmJE",
      "deletedDateTime": null,
      "appRoleId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "createdDateTime": "2021-02-02T04:22:45.9480566Z",
      "principalDisplayName": "Alex Wilber",
      "principalId": "cdb555e3-b33e-4fd5-a427-17fadacbdfa7",
      "principalType": "User",
      "resourceDisplayName": "dxprovisioning-graphapi-client",
      "resourceId": "8e881353-1735-45af-af21-ee1344582a4d"
    }
```

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63060344/5842326) that I can use the principalId to request the user object with like so:
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{prinicipalId}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7BprinicipalId%7D) . But this results in an error explaining I don't have permission.

After countless hours of googling I cannot find a solution to this problem. Is this just not possible?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the exact API you used.

Comment: I added the domain to the calls and added the servicePrincipal api endpoint, was this what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

To get all the user account (User display name, principle display name and email address) for an Azure enterprise app through PowerShell

```html
$app_name = "[app display name]"
$sp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "displayName eq '$app_name'"
$assignments = Get-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $sp.ObjectId -All $true
$assignments  # this will show all the users associated to the principal
```

Reference So Thread: [Azure: Get users assigned to enterprise application in Node JS/Power shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54147455/azure-get-users-assigned-to-enterprise-application-in-node-js-power-shell-scrip)